# Speed of repeat teleportation

Tags: super-powers, teleportation

Teleportation is a mightily fun superpower. What I have problems with is how many times this is abused for no reason at all. As an example, the Nightstalker (I think) in X-men can teleport short distances, but will one moment do a backflip just before teleporting and as he re-appears from his teleport he is suddenly not doing a somersault, has turned around, facing an opponent that was outside of his vision, and is halfway through a punch with enough energy behind it to knock an opponent unconscious. Basically, when exiting the teleport the character is in position with whatever energy it wants. It even allows them to teleport into/out of moving vehicles without problems.

To get a better idea what a realistic teleporting person would go through, I have the following assumptions:

- the person can teleport anywhere in their line of sight.
- accuracy of the teleport is based on how well they can see and aim for the target area.
- the person teleporting will inherit their bodily position, energy, and movement he had at the point of teleporting.
- all material the person is carrying is teleported with him. No molecular bonds are broken this way. So, clothes are teleported along but if you carry your friends arm it wont be ripped off - simply not teleported with you (unless you bodily carry your friend).
- the teleporter will swap with a volume of his size, swapping only with gasses or liquids but no solids totalling more than 200kg/m^3 (337 lb/yd^3) (the point is that you can still replace solids dispersed in air and water, not to make this a hard limit. Change the value to something that works if and when necessary). If the teleporter makes an error (say, placing his feet into the ground) he's teleported at maximum 1m (1.1yd) away from his chosen destination where no solids prevent his teleportation. If that is impossible, no teleportation happens.

Now imagine someone who decides to follow the highway towards his destination. He teleports a distance he feels safe with, so he doesn't accidentally end up on the highway. Each time he teleports he would logically need to regain his bearings rather than be able to teleport instantly again.

**The question is how fast would an average person be able to gain his bearings and teleport again?**

I originally thought this would be as simple as the average reflex time. But that only deals with reacting to one stimulus, not with appearing in an environment and choosing the next destination that is safe and in the direction you want.

Comment: There's no downside in attempting to teleport to an "unsafe" spot, as the teleportation simply doesn't happen in that case. It seems you could just teleport 10/100/1000 feet forward as fast as your reflexes allow, until something's in your way. Only when it doesn't work will you need to get your bearings.

Comment: Presumably if you teleport "up", whilst you fall you can get your bearings and thus be able to go well beyond the horizon in two jumps. (Nightcrawler, BTW ;)

Comment: I would liken it to the time it takes to get your barrings after jumping off of a trampoline.

Comment: Is bodily position also containing rotational coordinates or could I teleport myself while falling feet down and be going feet up to change my momentum?

Comment: @nuclearwang you can simulate how that goes actually. Open up google maps and randomly "teleport" trying to go to your destination. Its not that easy and you are extremely likely to teleport in harmful situations. Like in front of moving traffic, or into a position higher than the ground (a roof or simply because your aim was off) and eventually fall one or more stories to the ground. Randomly teleporting is like crossing the street blindfolded without paying attention to what you hear.

Comment: @ITAlex it contains rotational coordinates so no turning upside down. If you managed to teleport to the other end of the world you would be upside down and moving in the wrong rotational direction because of the earth rotation (another reason to keep it LOS as even a few kilometers or less up or down from the equator means incredible windspeed differences). Interesting to know how this would have helped getting your bearings after a teleport?

Comment: "_No molecular bonds are broken this way_" so with the aid of some suitable adhesive, can I glue you to something else (or myself), preventing you teleporting?

Comment: @StarfishPrime yes you could, assuming the target doesnt rip the glue area manually before teleporting. But I'm unsure how important that is for the question?

Comment: @Demigan there's a slight issue with how one might define "molecular bond". Would you include van der Waals bonds, for example?

Comment: @StarfishPrime the goal of that part is to prevent teleportation as a direct weapon, not to limit teleportation. You can assume that small amounts of bonds can be broken and that Van Der Waals bonds are only a factor if it can easily be weaponized.

Comment: @Demigan i'm wondering whether it implies that you can't guarantee your ability to teleport if you're in contact with some (perhaps many) kinds of solid and immobile objects. Or perhaps more humorously, you might find yourself teleporting out of your shoes if you didn't remember to do a little jump first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100521/discussion-between-demigan-and-starfish-prime).

Comment: This is very similar to the book 'Jumper'. In it the char can only jump to places that he could picture vividly in his mind. There is a part about half way through when he is hiking across the Nevada desert, I think, when he realizes that he can travel way more quickly this way. He gets himself a pair of strong binoculars, and basically starts picking places about 3-5 Km away, jumps to it, and then chooses another location. so maybe 30 sec between jumps while you study it?

Comment: @Demigan Teleporting into the air shouldn't be a problem - if you've teleported to a height that could cause bodily harm, you'll have half a second or more to teleport again before hitting the ground. That actually solves the problem with traffic and other ground-based hazards - just teleport 50 feet off the ground continuously, and you'll avoid almost anything that could pose a risk.

Comment: @NuclearWang so all you need is to teleport 50 feet into the air, then get enough bearings to keep teleporting 50 feet in the air despite accelerating downwards, limit the duration of your teleports so that you dont get enough velocity to injure yourself upon landing, be able to get your bearings and teleport into the ground in time and then get your bearings to see if you teleported right during that and not landed somewhere dangerous anyway which is hard because of the added difficulty of blindly teleporting forwards at 50 feet in the air. Isnt getting your bearings each jump easier?

Comment: I think it’s reasonable to use the “2 second rule” for driving as a low-end limit. That accounts for an average person having 20ms to hit the brakes. If they are amazingly fit this is a great measure. A baseball batter has 0.42 seconds to hit a 98mph fastball, so they really have less than 25 mS to decide and change their swing. I’d say teleporting more than twice per second is unrealistic, and the effect accumulates. No more than 3 jumps in a row.

Comment: @VogonPoet that is about the time I'm thinking off but I want to be SURE. In a car the environment changes gradually as the traffic moves along with you and things hidden from view earlier have time to reveal themselves. The car 2 second rule is to have time if the guy in front of you emergency breaks and thus is about reaction speed and how fast brakes work. In this case you teleport and have to evaluate everything, from the people walking (dont want to teleport and stand against them, personal space) to traffic, road condition, obstacles, height differences. Its a lot of info to go through.

Comment: Spot on. Also you really can’t do this more than a couple times without getting dizzy.

Answer (score 3):

## You were correct the first time.

The time needed to gain bearings would be roughly equal to one's reaction time, just as you originally thought.

You have to take into consideration that this person would likely have had this superpower for a pretty long time. Although it may have been challenging at first, through practice they would learn to adapt to suddenly being in random placements and positions. Their brain would learn to not only adapt, but to **expect** these kinds of situations.

Comment: I dont think I was right the first time. When you arrive at your destination you need to look for your next destination. A reflexive teleport would mean you teleport to an open space on the right side of the road. If there is a bend the right side you aim for might be the middle, it could be in front of a crossroads or a car exiting a parkingspot, an open spot could also mean a water-filled ditch. The problem as I see it is that you have to build a picture of the entire situation, rather than react to a single change in a reflexive action.

Comment: If you could react reflexively and learn this then we wouldnt need half as many rules on the road.

Comment: @Demigan I believe you are underestimating the speed at which humans can accurately perceive their surroundings and then make split-second decisions.

Comment: @Demigan There are rules of the road because it evolves human interactivity, which is an extremely complex system. Your question involves a single individual and his own perceptions. He can make his own rules based on his experience.

Comment: This is the answer that the game Champions uses.

Comment: @Overlord it involves a continuous situation that evolves over time, giving you time to spot dangers before you reach the next bit of destination and react to it. When teleporting you basically thrust yourself in a new situation. You have to consider the distance at which vision makes your jump inaccurate, bends in the road, crossroads, traffic, obstacles, clear space to land. Reactions on the road involve spotting a SINGLE stimulous in an already formed picture (say break lights) and reacting to that. Not having to consider ALL stimuli at the destination and their implications.

Comment: @ShadoCat I'm not interested in how a movie or game did it unless they had a solid reasoning behind it other than "game mechanics work like this/rule of cool".

Comment: @Demigan, the game mechanic was to account for the character's reaction time.  Any time the character could act, they could teleport.  SPEED was how many times a person could act in a 12 second span.  The SPEED for an average human was 2 with max being 4.  Those with super powers or certain machines could go faster.  According tot hat game, a normal who is highly trained could teleport once every 3 seconds if things were happening around them.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, for starters you are thinking of **Nightcrawler** from the X-men, and there is a valid explanation for why he can seemingly interrupt his acrobatics.  Nightcrawler doesn't teleport from one location to another on Earth, he teleports from Earth to an equivalent spot in Mephisto's Realm (basically Hell).  So he starts his flip on Earth, bamfs to Mephisto's realm, finishes the flip, runs a bit, turns around, and bamfs back to Earth.

**TL:DR -** As far as getting your bearings are concerned, your situation shouldn't be too bad.  If a normal person wanted to keep going in a straight line, there would not be any immediate problems, but a few minutes of constant teleportation might make you feel sick.

**Sound:** If you immediately travel a long distance, you are going to arrive at your destination before the sound waves which leave from the same spot as you at the same time.  The implication being that if it takes you a second or two to gather yourself between jumps, you might hear the same sounds over and over again.  While repetitive sound is by no means an issue, the exact sound signature from a source or sources might be problematic.  This can be counteracted by wearing noise cancelling headphones.

**Nausea:** The human brain does not like being rapidly presented with new scenery while not experiencing motion.  People playing VR games where they can quickly teleport short distances repeatedly sometimes report nausea and disorientation.  Though with practice, you could become accustomed to this.

**Temperature:** If you walk from one room into another which is just a degree different in temperature, you'll notice the change.  If you instantly inhabited a space with a different temperature, you'd certainly notice it.  If you did that about once per second, you may experience a crawling sensation on your skin, or other form of distracting feeling.  This could be distracting and slow down your teleportation time.

**Complex Maneuvers:** If you are doing some form of acrobatics, and teleport in the middle of it, it would be difficult for an untrained person to quickly recover, get their bearings, then teleport again.  Someone who has training in tumbling (like a Cirque Du Soleil performer) could probably do it on level terrain, but if the location they are teleporting to has different terrain, it would be difficult.

**Altitude:** If you were trying to quickly gain altitude (like teleporting up a mountain), there will definitely be problems which slow down your ability to gather yourself for another jump.  Basically, the pressure change would be the same as a scuba diver surfacing too fast, and you'd get the bends.  This and the thinning of the air could make you pass ought, or impair your senses and judgement so that you can't concentrate well enough to teleport again.

Comment: A good point about the VR Nausea. Ironically, It is much easier to get used to teleportation than from frictionless/reactionless movement. There are plenty of games that I can rapidly teleport pretty decent distances and not get nausea.